# How can I remove a value from an enum in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, enums

I have got a table with an `ENUM` in it containing 3 values: `one`, `two`, `three`.
The table is already containing data, but `ENUM`value `two` isn't used at the moment, so I want to delete it from the `ENUM`. The result would be an `ENUM` with only 2 values: `one`, `three`.

Can I just use an `ALTER TABLE` statement and say like:

```
ALTER TABLE 'tablename' CHANGE 'enumname' ENUM('one', 'three');
```

Comment: Your attempt is ok , but little changes require ,Try the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :-

```
alter table tablename
change `columname`  `columname` enum ('one', 'three');
```

Its working fine.

Answer (score 4):

Enums are saved as integers so all your rows with `enum="one"` is actually equal to `1`, `enum="two"` is `2` and `enum="tree"` is `3`.

Seems MySQL is doing all the magic to change those values if enum names match so you just need to make sure there are no rows with 'two'

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef76d/1

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (`name` VARCHAR(32), `enumname` ENUM('one', 'two', 'three'));
INSERT INTO `tablename` VALUES ('one', 'one'),('two', 'two'),('three', 'three');
DELETE FROM `tablename` WHERE `enumname`=2;
ALTER TABLE `tablename` MODIFY `enumname` ENUM('one', 'three');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. Here is an example :

```
ALTER TABLE `database`.`tablename`
CHANGE `enumname` `enumname` ENUM('one','two')
CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Try it on your testenvironment fist, because it can take a while for big tables?